# Reactjs Child Component not updating

Tags: reactjs, components, updating, rerender

I'm having trouble updating the state of the child component.
If i upload an image it doesn't appear in the ReactChromakeyedImage component. (which is a package i use)

```
import './App.css';
import ReactChromakeyedImage from 'react-chromakeyed-image';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
   function handleChange(e) {
       console.log(e.target.files);
       setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));

   }


  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h2>Add Image:</h2>
    <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
    <h3>Original</h3>
    <img style={{width: "400px"}}  src={file} />

    <h3>Chromakeyed</h3>

    <ReactChromakeyedImage src={file} style={{width: "400px"}} findColor="#3CC156" replaceColor="#FFFFFF" tolerance={70}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: It probably isnt this, but is it possible you need to add `height` as well as width? And also to pass them as HTML attributes. `<ReactChromakeyedImage src={file} width="400"  height="400" findColor="#3CC156" replaceColor="#FFFFFF" tolerance={70}/>`

Comment: No errors. If i select an image and save the project it shows the image. :/ @adsy no difference :(

Comment: First thing I would do just to clean up which can go a long way to make an issues easier to address is instead of using the style tag go ahead and just create a css file and assign style there.  Also if you provide a sandbox its a lot easier to find the issue and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's a bug in the lib. Internally, it checks the `img` tag it uses inside to see if the `complete` property has been set on the image HTML element. This goes to `true` when the browser has painted the image. However, it only does this on every rerender, and it it also does not wait until it becomes true (it's asynchronous). That's why it's flaky.

Really the lib needs to be forked to fix, but there is a pretty horrible workaround you could do (this is really not nice at all, but it might be your only option unless you fork).

In this solution we attach a load listener using the DOM API (bad!) and then force a rerender, which triggers the library to check the completed property again.

Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-voice-bhxw36?file=/src/App.js:0-1085.

```
import ReactChromakeyedImage from "react-chromakeyed-image";
import React, { useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const containerRef = useRef();
  const [, forceReload] = useState(0);
  function handleChange(e) {
    setFile(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;
    containerRef.current.querySelector("img").addEventListener("load", () => {
      forceReload((x) => x + 1);
    });
  }, [file]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Add Image:</h2>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <h3>Original</h3>
       <img style={{width: "400px"}}  src={file} />

      <h3>Chromakeyed</h3>

      {file && (
        <div ref={containerRef}>
          <ReactChromakeyedImage
            src={file}
            findColor="#3CC156"
            replaceColor="#FFFFFF"
            tolerance={70}
            width="400"
            height="400"
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you adsy this worked. The only think is that the picture ignores the width and height set in chroma component. Changing it to style={{width: "400px"}} helped.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this library, and it could be a bug or simply that values are just stored and don't get updated if you change the value of the image. My advice would be just to make the component re-render to update it. The simplest way is to add a `key` to it, whenever this `key` changes the component will get re-rendered. I use `file.name` in this example but any changing value would be fine.

```js
    <ReactChromakeyedImage key={file.name} src={file} style={{width: "400px"}} findColor="#3CC156" replaceColor="#FFFFFF" tolerance={70}/>
```

Comment: I thought this too at first. However after playing with it still didn't work. The library checks if the image loaded on every rerender. However, it also doesn't wait for the image to be loaded and update itself about it's presence. It's a race condition.